# Piece-wise second order differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, homogeneous-equation

Suppose I have some function $f(x)$ which is equal to $kx$ when $x$ is negative and $-kx$ when $x$ is positive, and I have the following differential equation : $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-k|x|=f(x)$$

My idea is to break this into two parts. For $x<0$, we have $|x|=-x$, hence :

$$D^2x=kx$$

Similarly, when $x>0$, we have $|x|=x$, and so :

$$D^2x=-kx$$

I don't see how to proceed from here. For the negative region, I'm getting a solution that is a combination of exponential functions, and for the positive region, I'm getting a solution that is a combination of sinusoidal functions.

However, I also think that, in the negative direction, just as $|x|\rightarrow-x$, we should also change $D^2x\rightarrow -D^2x$. In that case, we can rewrite the entire equation as $$D^2x=-kx$$ and allow $x$ to have positive and negative values. Then the entire solution is a sinusoid.

However, I'm not sure, if in the negative region $D^2x\rightarrow -D^2x$. Is this correct, and if not, how do I solve this equation?

Moreover, if I had a differential equation of the form: $$D^2|x|=-k|x|$$, then I could have removed the mod and solved this equation as $$(D^2-k)x=0$$, and allowed $x$ to be both positive and negative, right ?

Comment: You're on the right track. Note this is exactly the acceleration of simple harmonic motion for positive x, so you should get complex exponentials in that region, real exponential solutions to the left of the origin.

Comment: You should continue with what you started. Considering two separate cases: $x''=kx$ when $x\leq0$ and $x''=-kx$ when $x\geq0,$ is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

For $k=0$, $\boxed{x(t) = c_1t+c_2.}$

For $k \neq 0$, start by multiplying both sides of your differential equation by $x'(t)$ and integrating in terms of $t$,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}\phantom{t}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right) = -k |x|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2 = -k\int|x| \mathrm{d}x.
$$

Therefore,
$$
\boxed{t + c_1 = \pm \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x'}{\sqrt{-2k\int|x| \mathrm{d}x}}.}
$$

1. If $x>0$, $\int |x|\mathrm{d}x = \int x\mathrm{d}x = x^2/2 + c_2$. Therefore,
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   t + c_1 &= \pm \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{c_2-kx^2}} = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{k}x}{\sqrt{c_2-kx^2}}\right) \\
   &\Rightarrow \boxed{x(t) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{c_2}{k}}\sin\left(\sqrt{k}(t+c_1)\right)\mathrm{sgn}\left(\cos\left(\sqrt{k}(t+c_1)\right)\right).}
   \end{aligned}
   $$
2. If $x<0$, $\int |x|\mathrm{d}x = -\int x\mathrm{d}x = -x^2/2 + c_2$. Therefore,
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   t + c_1 &= \pm \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{c_2+kx^2}} = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{k}x}{\sqrt{c_2+kx^2}}\right) \\
   &\Rightarrow \boxed{x(t) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{c_2}{k}}\sinh\left(\sqrt{k}(t+c_1)\right).}
   \end{aligned}
   $$